# Block direct access from pdf, but let server request it for pdfjs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, pdf, joomla

I know there are a lot of questions about that but unfortunately, any of those work for me.

I'm trying to block pdf from direct access, but let the server show it in PDFJS.

That's what I can get when trying to view the pdf in PDFJS : File is missing, 403 forbidden, unexpected server response

What I've tried and didn't work :

- Deny from all (.htaccess)
- RewriteRule : 
  `RewriteEngine on rewriteRule
  ^path/to/folder? index.php [L]`
- Access file from server root path while having "Deny from all" in htaccess
- Deny from all with "allow from 127.0.0.1" / "allow from localhost"

Here's the code of the php file that execute all the verifications

```
    <?php

            // Loading Joomla User core Files
            define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
            define('JPATH_BASE', '../');
            require_once ( '../includes/defines.php' );
            require_once ( '../includes/framework.php' );

            // Create the Application
            $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

            echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html dir='ltr' mozdisallowselectionprint moznomarginboxes><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='web/style/style.css'></head>";

            // Error Messages
            $error1 = "Veuillez vous connecter."; // You need to Log-in
            $error2 = "Votre compte n'est pas abonné au journal électronique. <br /> <span style='font-size: 0.6em;'>Merci de visiter la <a href='' target='_blank'>page d'abonnement</a> si vous souhaiter vous y inscrire.</span>"; // Your account isn't subscribed to our web newspaper
            $error3 = "Une erreur s'est produite durant votre requête. <br /> <span>Merci de réessayer. Si cette erreur persiste, merci de nous en faire part à travers le <a href='' target='_blank'>formulaire du support technique</a>.</span>"; // You encountered an error during your request. Plese refresh the page
            $error4 = "Le lien ne dirige vers aucun pdf. <br /> <span style='font-size: 0.6em;'> Merci d'utiliser un lien correcte."; // You link doesn't lead to any pdf. Please use a correct link
            $error5 = "Le fichier pdf est introuvable. <br /> <span style='font-size: 0.6em;'>Il s'aggit soit d'une erreur du lien URL ou bien le fichier pdf demandé n'existe plus. Veuillez vous refferrez à nos archives si vous souhaitez retrouver une ancienne édition.</span>"; // There's an error in your link.

            if(empty($_GET["page"])) {
                $page = "";
            } else {
                $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET["page"]);
            }

            // Get pdf
            $file = "./pdf/" . $page . ".pdf";

            // Get account
            $user = JFactory::getUser();

            // Define user id
            $userId = $user->id;

            // Connect to databases
            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbName");

            // Define query to execute if page isn't empty and file exists
            $resultabo = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE user_id='$userId' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

            // STARTING FILES REQUEST
            if(empty($page)) {
                    // If nothing is entered in the page, display error
                    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
                    echo "<p id='errorMsg'>" . $error4 . "</p>";
                    exit(0);

            } elseif(file_exists($file)) {

                // If file is existing, continu php

                // Check wether the user is a visitor or a registered member
                if($userId == 0) {

                    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
                    echo "<p id='errorMsg'>" . $error1 . "</p>";
                    exit(0);

                } else {

                    // Controling wether the user is logged-in in a subscribed account
                    while($row = $resultabo->fetch_assoc()) {

                        // Getting account type for checking if subcribed
                        $abo = $row["account_id"];

                                if($abo == 1) {

                                    // Note : 1 is a registered member but not subscribed

                                    // echo message : Your account is not subscribed to our website, please go on WebsiteName to subscribe.   
                                    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
                                    echo "<p id='errorMsg'>" . $error2 . "</p>";
                                    exit(0); 

                                } else {

                                    // Note : All $abo between 6 and 7 are "subscribed"
                                    // SUCCESS, PDF IS BEING SHOWED

                                    // Viewer.html
                                    echo 'PDFJS html code from viewer.html (code example)';

                                }

                    }
                }

            } else {

                // Cannot find file, give an error.
                header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
                echo "<p id='errorMsg'>" . $error5 . "</p>";
                exit(0);
             }       

        echo "</head></html>";

        exit(0);

?>
```

Couldn't paste the entire html viewer code, but it's the same as the example given as a demo on their website. For displaying the file, I changed the DEFAULT_URL with my $file .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to put files outside of project folder, somthing like that :

```
-joomla folder
--administrator
--components
--...
-pdf
```

In this way your pdfs files can not be accessible from url, but remains accesible from script :

```
$file = JPATH_ROOT."/../pdf/" . $page . ".pdf";
```

Comment: Thanks. However, as mentioned above, server root does not work for some reason. Probably a script that is changing/cleaning the file path in pdf.js or viewer.js. Here's the error I get when I use your code `"Message: Missing PDF "http://domain.name/pdf/filename.pdf"`.

Comment: So you should call a php page that return content of pdf with application/pdf as content-type

Comment: Not sure what you mean because it's already a php file that display a pdf. However, the server root is sort of working but when I'm trying to set it as a path, it automatically adds it to the domain name. Example : `Message: Missing PDF "https://domain.name/server/root/path/domain.name/pdf/filename.pdf"`.